# How does one access a ViewData item which contains a special character with the ViewBag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

A toy example,

```
ViewData["rat"] = "Rodent";
var blaw = ViewBag.rat;

ViewData["dig/dug"] =  "Game";
// var blaw2 = Viewbag.dig/dug;
```

The last line of course does not work.  How would I access "dig/dug" through the ViewBag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use underscore (or some another allowed symbol) instead of slash. Slash is not allowed:

```
ViewData["dig_dug"] =  "Game";
```

Since ViewBag is dynamic dig/dug will be a property of dynamic object.

You can't use some special symbols(/,. etc..) within name of properties:

```
public string Dig\Dug {get;set;} // compilation time error
```

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Thanks for the confirmation.